# forms authentication in a load balanced environment

Tags: cookies, encryption, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, load-balancing

I am currently working with integrating forms authentication in mvc4 application. Once a user is authenticated, an encrypted cookie is written to their PC.

My application will be installed on a load balanced environment where a user can hit any of the balanced web servers.

Question I have around encryption of cookies, will there be any issue if the cookie is encrypted on server A, and the next request the user makes is to server B and the cookie needs to be decrypted to proceed? Any problem regarding encrypting on one server and decrypting on the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure machine keys are same across all servers. Follow [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0cf270c-4cfa-4bc3-b279-22c9de7f9373.aspx) for IIS7.

Comment: Thats all that needs to be done to ensure all will work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

No problem at all. Just be sure that the cookies are for the whole domain (mysite.com.) to prevent problems if you have a structure like server1.mysite.com. After that, for sure, keeping in mind that keys are available to each server, you should have no problem.